# Should I use PASS before NICK, USER?

Tags: irc

I'm playing with am IRC bot (in python), and have been looking at some of the many useful examples.

One thing I can't get straight... **Should I use `PASS` before `NICK`, `USER`?**

In RFC 1459, as well as several of the RFC 2810..13, it's recommend to use `PASS` before `NICK`, `USER`. Yet nobody seems to follow this practise. And the bots seem to work just fine without `PASS`.

When should I use `PASS` and why?

Answer (score 0):

PASS is used to provide a connection password to an IRC server, though most public IRC servers don't usually set a connection password. PASS only required if a password is required to connect to a server. (Note the difference between connection authentication and authenticating to network services such as NickServ).

NICK and USER are enough to register a new connection to an IRC server. However, since PASS is optional, it must be specified before the connection registration is completed. This means PASS cannot be the last one to be sent from the trio of NICK, USER, and PASS.

Answer (score 0):

PASS is evaluated at the moment the connection becomes fully "registered" to the server - meaning, the point at which the server has all the required information to evaluate whether the connection should be allowed or not, and if allowed, to introduce the client to the network. (This is prior to, and separate from any registration to IRC services like NickServ). Up until the point at which the server sees either SERVER, or *both* and NICK and USER commands, PASS is accepted,

PASS may actually be sent multiple times, generally subject only to registration timeouts, but according to the RFC only the last PASS seen before a complete registration is evaluated - sending PASS more than once simply overwrites the previous value.

If the connection is from a server, then PASS is required, and has to be sent before the SERVER command.

Ordinary users typically do not need to send a password to connect - typically it's only necessary for connections that are privileged in some way - for example a user that has higher connection limits, flood control exemption, a IRC operator with a masked hostname in the server config, larger send buffers, longer ping timeouts, or is permitted to connect in spite of geographic restrictions might have a password defined.

Some networks choose to use PASS to authenticate to IRC services like NickServ, but this has become uncommon because this usage conflicts with the standard use of PASS, and because authentication to services usually requires two parameters (an account name and a password) and PASS is defined to take one.

If you are looking to authenticate to services at connection time, most networks with services implement [SASL Authentication](http://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/sasl-3.1.html) extensions to the IRC protocol specifically for this purposes.